# where to place videos to stream android

Tags: android, web

i want my android app to stream video. I have a website stored in a web server. The question is: where should i put the video files? Can i put them in my website's root directory, or do i need a Streaming Server too? I hope this question is not out of topic.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If they are MP4s marked as "safe for streaming" (MOOV atom is before the first MDAT atom, such as via `MP4Box -hint`), you can host them on any Web server.

Comment: well, i thought i should only save the video as .mp4 and then i could host them anywhere. It seems a little more complicated than that. So how can i do all that? do you have any useful link?

Comment: @madcoderz: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/f70f182067c0c9b6/35c84e035d833b1a