# not able to play video in the emulator

Tags: android

```
public class VideoViewActivity extends Activity {
    private String vSource;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

              setContentView(R.layout.videoviewacti);
              VideoView vView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videovw);
              vView.requestFocus();
              String LINK = ConstantData.urlVideo;
              Log.i("path of video",""+LINK);
              vView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(LINK));

              //vView.setVideoPath("sdcard/test30fps.mp4");
              MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(this);
              vView.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
              vView.start();
    }
}
```

here the video doesn't play in the emulator.It shows the error like "Can not play video"
video format is mp4 on the webservice.
when it opens the video file then the controls of the mediaplayer get disabled.

Comment: possible duplicate of [where to place videos to stream android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288883/where-to-place-videos-to-stream-android)

Comment: my videos are already uploaded. i have to just play those videos to my application only.

Comment: Please read the question I linked to more closely.