# How to play video using Intent in Android?

Tags: android, video, android-intent

Few weeks ago I decided to make an app, this app contained just video links that allows the users to watch clips whenever they click any button link.

I am using this code to play video:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("http://www.yourvideo.mp4"), "video/mp4"); 
view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

However, in some cases this code doesn't work in several devices, some users of my app said it force closes the entire app whenever they press any link. I actually tried it in my G1 and Droid X, it worked perfectly fine.

Is there anything I am doing wrong? Please help me, I would really appreciate it a lot.

Comment: could you have a problem if they started in portrait mode then switched to landscape mode?

Comment: As soon as you press the link button, the whole app will be in landscape mode, It never switch to portrait mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, the video may have issues, as not all videos are [safe for streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288883/where-to-place-videos-to-stream-android).

Second, not all devices may have activities set up to support `ACTION_VIEW` on `video/mp4` files that are streamed. You should use `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivities()` to confirm whether the `startActivity()` call will find a match, or handle the `ActivityNotFoundException` that you get.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote this :

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("http://www.yourvideo.mp4"), "video/mp4");
```

Then i add the permission : `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAG`E , to my manifest.