# How can I play MP4 video through a direct link in Android video player?

Tags: android, android-intent, video, android-video-player

I am making an Android application in which i need to play mp4 video in the android default native video player through a direct downloadable link.

To open the Android video player I am using the following code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://b.revvolution.com/video/albums-3ry/newshare-der-34972.mp4?download=1"));

intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("http://b.revvolution.com/video/albums-3ry/newshare-der-34972.mp4?download=1"), "video/*");

startActivity(intent);
```

Here the URL is direct downloadable link for the mp4 video.
This code opens the video player but video is not loaded in the video player

I have also used this URL

```
http://b.revvolution.com/video/albums-3ry/newshare-der-34972.mp4
```

This URL contains a html5 video player but the video is not loaded in Android video player

But when i use a link of 3GP video like

```
http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/AndroidCommercial.3gp
```

Then it works.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Try the way I did

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("http://www.yourvideo.mp4"), "video/mp4");
```

Then add the permission : `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` , to manifest.

---

## update

First, the video may have issues, as not all videos are [safe for streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288883/where-to-place-videos-to-stream-android).

Second, not all devices may have activities set up to support `ACTION_VIEW` on `video/mp4` files that are streamed. You should use `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivities()` to confirm whether the `startActivity()` call will find a match, or handle the `ActivityNotFoundException` that you get.

You need to check the [Android Video Encoding Recommandations](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) . Make sure that your video is encoded with the supported code, and your video respects the resolutions.After the video were properly encoded the streamming worked.

Also if you didn't noticed yet, usually the emulator does not play them, and you'll have to test on a real device.

Comment: I am testing it in real device but i think the problem is in video streaming

Comment: Is the video streaming problem occured at my side or at the server side ?? Please tell me

Comment: thanks, It work for me (real device and simulator) with "startActivity(intent);"